# How do I get a list of all available time zones in C++?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-chrono

I would like to somehow enumerate what time zones are available, and if possible, where my current time zone fits in this enumeration, with portable C++.

Answer (score 7):

This is not possible (portably) in C++ prior to C++20.  But it becomes trivial to do in C++20.

To start, in C++20 there is a type [`std::chrono::time_zone`](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.zone.timezone) which encapsulates a geographic area, and its rules for UTC offsets over the years.  In general the rule is a function of the year.  These time zones model the [IANA time zone database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones).

Additionally there are [`std::chrono::time_zone_link`](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.zone.link).  A `time_zone_link` is like a type alias, but for `time_zone`.  It is nothing more than an alternative name for another `time_zone`.  You can use the name of either a `time_zone`, or a `time_zone_link` in a call to `std::chrono::locate_zone("continent/city")` which when successful, will return a `time_zone const*`.

Below is code which iterates over all available `time_zone`s, all available `time_zone_link`s, and identifies your current `time_zone`:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace chrono;

    cout << "All available time zones:\n";
    for (auto& tz : get_tzdb().zones)
        cout << tz.name() << '\n';

    cout << "\nAll time zone links:\n";
    for (auto& tz : get_tzdb().links)
        cout << tz.name() << '\n';

    cout << "\nMy time zone:\n";
    cout << current_zone()->name() << '\n';
}
```

[Demo.](https://wandbox.org/permlink/gwAXlc3DPAnW3bLW)

Head of output:

```
All available time zones:
Africa/Abidjan
Africa/Algiers
Africa/Bissau
Africa/Cairo
Africa/Casablanca
Africa/Ceuta
...
```

Any of these names can be used with `locate_zone` and that can be used to translate between UTC and the local time, in either direction.  For example:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <format>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    auto tz = std::chrono::locate_zone("Australia/Sydney");
    auto now_utc = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto now_syd = std::chrono::zoned_time{tz, now_utc};
    std::cout << std::format("{:%F %T %Z}", now_utc) << '\n';
    std::cout << std::format("{:%F %T %Z}", now_syd) << '\n';
    std::cout << std::format("{:%F %T %Z}", now_syd.get_sys_time()) << '\n';
}
```

Example output:

```
2023-09-27 04:00:11.408252895 UTC
2023-09-27 14:00:11.408252895 AEST
2023-09-27 04:00:11.408252895 UTC
```

[Demo.](https://wandbox.org/permlink/KFTwhMyYhPQHeTEf)

Finally note that if this isn't the precision you're looking for, you can change to *your* desired precision in **one** place, and all of the subsequent arithmetic, conversions, and formatting *automatically* adjust:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <format>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    auto tz = std::chrono::locate_zone("Australia/Sydney");
    auto now_utc = std::chrono::floor<std::chrono::seconds>
                       (std::chrono::system_clock::now());
    auto now_syd = std::chrono::zoned_time{tz, now_utc};
    std::cout << std::format("{:%F %T %Z}", now_utc) << '\n';
    std::cout << std::format("{:%F %T %Z}", now_syd) << '\n';
    std::cout << std::format("{:%F %T %Z}", now_syd.get_sys_time()) << '\n';
}
```

Example output:

```
2023-09-27 04:00:11 UTC
2023-09-27 14:00:11 AEST
2023-09-27 04:00:11 UTC
```